# Check if a matrix has a diagonal of ones MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Matlab code to check if a matrix has a diagonal line of 1s or is a UNIT LOWER triangular matrix.

Currently using `isstril ~= 1` to check if it is a lower triangular matrix.

I y ried `isdiag` but it cant have non zero elements except the diagonal.

But I need to check as well if there is a diagonal of 1s going through the matrix.

This is the syntax I'm using at the moment:

```matlab
if all(diag(L)~=1)
    error("must be a unit lower triangular matrix")
end
if istril(L) == 1
    error("must be a lower triangular matrix"); 
end
```

For example to check a nxn matrix

```
L = [ 1 1 1 ; 0 1 1 ; 0 0 1 ]
```

Comment: How about `all(diag(L) == 1)`?

Comment: i used if all(diag(L) ~=1) , using an error text after the if but it still shows an output of nan instead of going to the error msg, after testing the matrix when one of the diagonals is a non 1 element

Comment: Note that `all(diag(L)==1)` is not the same as `~all(diag(L)~=1)`. I think you want to do either `~all(diag(L)==1)` or `any(diag(L)~=1)`.